# show the button if the condition is true according to the input data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have a input text field i get the data from database using javascript and php.
**get.html** get the data by javascript

```
    function showUser(str) {
        if (str == "") {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        } else {
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
                // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                }
            };
            xmlhttp.open("GET","get.php?q="+str,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    }

<input type="text" id="name" onblur="showUser(this.value)">
<input type="buton" name="">
<br>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here...</b></div>
```

**get.php**to connect database to show data

```
<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Could not Connect with Sql");
mysql_select_db("dialog",$con)  or die("Could connect to Database");
$sql="SELECT * FROM customer WHERE cx_number = '".$q."'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>cx_number</th>
<th>package</th>
<th>balance</th>
</tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['cx_number'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['package'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['balance'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

now my question is how to show the button to increase package amount if package balance is zero

Comment: why don't you make one parent div and put that button inside that div?

Comment: yes sir i little bit confuse about that .if you don't mind please explain me

Comment: your ajax code will always return one row or multiple?

Comment: Where do u want increase package button ?

Comment: @prakashtank sir it return whole data column according tomy input value

Comment: @PunithJain after enter my input value it will show the output under each column for balance value which is 0 only button should display to increase package amount

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need it for each user just replace in get.php

```
echo "<td>" . $row['balance'] . "</td>";
```

to

```
echo "<td>" . $row['balance'] ; 
if ($row['balance'] <= 0) echo "<button>Your button </button>";
echo "</td>";
```

You also can do it on browser side. Add after

```
document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
```

code like this

```
$("#txtHint tr").each(function() { // cicle through each row
    el=$this.find( "td:eq(2)" ) // get td with index==2.(firs==0, secon==1)...
    if (parseFloat(el.html()<=0)  { // check if it's 0 or lower
        el.append( $( "Your button or link html here" ) ); // add button
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can change it in your div like this :

```
function showUser(str) {
        if (str == "") {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        } else {
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
                // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                }
            };
            xmlhttp.open("GET","get.php?q="+str,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    }

<input type="text" id="name" onblur="showUser(this.value)">
<div id="txtHint">
<b>Person info will be listed here...</b></div>
```

in your ajax file :

```
 <?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Could not Connect with Sql");
mysql_select_db("dialog",$con)  or die("Could connect to Database");
$sql="SELECT * FROM customer WHERE cx_number = '".$q."'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>cx_number</th>
<th>package</th>
<th>balance</th>
</tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['cx_number'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['package'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['balance'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>". if( $row['balance'] == 0) {  '<input type="button" name="" value="your value"> } '. "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```